# php substr function not working?

Tags: php, substr

I have the following code, outputting a price, like 1000,00

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to add a simple substr function as to remove the decimal divider and the decimal numbers. I'm looking to do:

```
<span class="price"><?php echo substr($price_html, 0, -3); ?></span>
```

For some reason, the price is not being affected.

If however I apply substr to a string, like:

```
<?php echo substr('€1.000,00', 0, -3); ?>
```

It magically works, I get €1.000 as expected. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: currently I am getting €1000,00 and I want to get €1000

Comment: What do you get now and what do you expect?

Comment: Show a var_dump() of `$price_html` before the substr() because it may contain characters after the `00`

Comment: Added an update. Currently I am getting €1000,00 and I want to get €1000

Comment: @MarkBaker I would bet on a html tag either p tag or a bold tag :D

Comment: You are right, my $price_html; contains a span!

Comment: `get_price_html()` sounds like a nasty method. Keep your price as an int and use printf/sprintf to format your strings.

Comment: `echo str_replace(',00', '', $price_html);` may be a better alternative

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker that solved my problem, thank you also about the var dump thing